# Display custom image as cursor

Tags: css, google-chrome, mouse-cursor

I've been trying to display a custom cursor icon on my site.

I've tried

```css
html {
  cursor: url("https://i.imgur.com/hjMEGpb.png"), auto;
}
```

I don't see it's working.

What did I do wrong ?

I'm testing on the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably related to the image size which a bit big. Use a smaller one:

[image]

```css
html {
  cursor: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu8CP.png"), auto;
}
```

Comment: "While the specification does not limit the cursor image size, user agents commonly restrict them to avoid potential misuse. For example, on Firefox and Chromium cursor images are restricted to 128x128 pixels by default, but it is recommended to limit the cursor image size to 32x32 pixels"
 
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor?retiredLocale=de#icon_size_limits